# Testing iOS apps on devices that are faster than the actual target?

Tags: ios, testing

I'm planning to have an iPad 4th generation and I don't want to go hunting for a 3rd gen since it's discontinued afaik.

Is there a framework or anything similar that makes it possible to degrade the performance on software level so that I can get a vague idea of how fast the app will be on a less powerful device ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is (and I don't think there is), I wouldn't use it for real world performance testing.  In fact, the iPhone / iPad simulator really isn't the right tool at all for performance testing.  It doesn't have the same processor, memory, etc.  When testing performance you should test with a real device.